# How to use ContextProvider function in the same file with <ContextProvider/>?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create a context for user authenticated.It like

```
interface IAuthContext{
    isAuthenticated:boolean
    setIsAuthenticated:Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
    checkAuth: () => Promise<void>
    logoutClient : () =>void,
}

const defaultIsAuthenticated = false
export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({
    isAuthenticated:defaultIsAuthenticated,
    setIsAuthenticated: () =>{},
    checkAuth:() => Promise.resolve(),
    logoutClient : () =>{}
})

const AuthContextProvider= ({children} : {children:ReactNode}) =>{
    const [isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated] = useState(defaultIsAuthenticated)

    const checkAuth = async () =>{
        //check if token is existing
        const token = JwtManager.getToken()

        if(token) setIsAuthenticated(true)

        else{
            const success = await JwtManager.getRefreshToken()
            if(success) setIsAuthenticated(true)
        }
    }

    const authContextData = {
        isAuthenticated,
        setIsAuthenticated,
        checkAuth,
        logoutClient
    }
    return(<AuthContext.Provider value={authContextData}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>)
}
export default AuthContextProvider
```

I use it in _app.tsx , but it not work. Whenever i move it to another component, it work.
This is code in _app.tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { checkAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const authenticate = async () => {
      await checkAuth();
    };
    authenticate();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ChakraProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I must use CheckAuth() in _app.tsx for user authenticated, so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's because `<AuthContextProvider>` must be a parent (or anywhere in the hierarchy above) the component that contains `checkAuth`. One option would be to move your auth provider up one step to your `index.tsx` and wrap your `<MyApp>` component with it.

Comment: Your option work with React, but not with Nextjs, do you have another idea?

Comment: Well, all you need to accomplish is getting `checkAuth` to be in a child component beneath where you're returning `AuthContextProvider`. It's up to you how you want to exactly compose that. But in order to use contexts properly, you need to have at least two components working together—one that renders the Provider and one descendant who then uses that context.

Comment: oh i understood your idea. thanks and have a nice day!